# Limits and Continuity

Tags: limits

> The function $$f(x)=(\sin{3x})^{\tan^2(3x)}$$ is not defined at $x=\pi/6$. The 
>   value of f(π/6), so that the f is continuous at x=π/6 is?
>
> - A) $e$
> - B) $e^{-1/2}$
> - C) $e^{1/2}$
> - D) $e^2$

---

I have approached it like this

Since $f(x)^{g(x)}$ at $ x\to \frac{\pi}{6}$ is $1^{\infty} $ so we can write this as

$$e^{(g(x)(f(x)-1))}$$

but how to solve $$ \tan^{2}(3x) (\sin(3x)-1) $$ further so that it doesn't lead to infinity?

---

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the expression with the exponential (e^... and so on). Use the definition of continuity, and look at the limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your way using

- $\lim_{t\to 0}(1+t)^{\frac 1t} = e$ with $t = \sin 3x - 1$ for $x \to \frac{\pi}{6}$ you have

$$(\sin{3x})^{\tan^2(3x)}= \left( \left(1+t  \right)^{\frac 1t}\right)^{(\sin 3x - 1)\tan^2 3x}$$

So, it remains to calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}}(\sin 3x - 1)\tan^2 3x$. Noting, that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}}\sin^2 3x =1$, we find using L'Hospital
\begin{eqnarray}\frac{\sin 3x -1}{\cos^2 3x}
& = & 2\frac{\sin 3x -1}{1+\cos6x} \\
& \stackrel{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}}{\sim} &-\frac{\cos 3x}{\sin 6x} \\
& \stackrel{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}}{\sim} &\frac 12\frac{\sin 3x}{\cos 6x} \\
& \stackrel{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}}{\longrightarrow} & -\frac 12\\
\end{eqnarray}

Hence, $\boxed{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}}(\sin{3x})^{\tan^2(3x)} = e^{-\frac 12}}$. So,  answer B is right.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi/6}~(\sin(3x))^{\tan^2(3x)}$$
Let $x-\pi/6=y$, then
$$L=\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} =(\cos 3y)^{\cot^2 3y}$$
For very small values of $y$, we have $$\cos 3y \approx 1-9y^2/2,~ \cot 3y \approx 1/(3y)$$ Then
$$L=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \left[1-\frac{9y^2}{2} \right]^{1/(9y^2)}= e^{-1/2}$$
So for continuity $f(\pi/6)=1/\sqrt{e}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using $x=y+\frac \pi 6$, the expresion is
$$A=\Big[\cos (3 y)\Big]^{\cot ^2(3 y)}\implies \log(A)={\cot ^2(3 y)}\log(\cos(3y))$$ Let $3y=t$ to make 
$$\log(A)={\cot ^2(t)}\log(\cos(t))$$ Now, using composition of Taylor series
$$\cos(t)=1-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^4}{24}+O\left(t^6\right)$$
$$\log(\cos(t))=-\frac{t^2}{2}-\frac{t^4}{12}+O\left(t^8\right)$$
$$\cot(t)=\frac{1}{t}-\frac{t}{3}-\frac{t^3}{45}+O\left(t^5\right)$$
$$\cot^2(t)=\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{t^2}{15}+O\left(t^4\right)$$
$$\log(A)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{t^2}{4}+O\left(t^4\right)$$
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}+\frac{t^2}{4 \sqrt{e}}+O\left(t^4\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.